# Cómo almaceno el input.value de dos o más inputs dinámicos y, con un input radio, seleccionar uno de todos los inputs dinámicos y almacenarlo aparte

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Pues quiero que el Nivel del compañero [ i ] se almacene fuera de la iteración y además si tiene el radio activo seleccionado que ese se muestre por otro lado.
Algo asi como "Nivel del compañero activo = X" y "nivel del compañero [ i ] = Y"

```js
//buddy input
let buddy = document.getElementById("companion")
//buddy lvl inputs
let buddyResult = document.getElementById("companion-inputs")
//funcion que crea inputs dinámicos (text + radio)
function createResult(){
  buddyResult.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= buddy.value; i++) {
    const element = buddy.value[i];
    buddyResult.innerHTML +=
     `<div class= "lvl-check">
     <input class="clases" id="companion-${i}" type="number" placeholder="Nivel del compañero nº${i}"/>
     <input type="radio" name="activo" />
     <label for="companion-${i}">activo</label>
     </div>`;
  }
}
```

```css
.lvl-check{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.clases{
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!--al poner un número, se generan X inputs-->
<input onchange="createResult()" class="clases" id="companion" type="number" placeholder=" Nº de compañeros"/>

<!--aqui dentro  se generan los inputs dinámicos con los radio-->
<div id="companion-inputs">
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir *quiero que el Nivel del compañero [ i ] se almacene fuera de la iteración y además si tiene el radio activo seleccionado que ese se muestre por otro lado. Algo asi como "Nivel del compañero activo = X" y "nivel del compañero [ i ] = Y"*? ¿Que se almacene dónde? ¿que se muestre dónde? Si te explicas mejor y/o pones un ejemplo quizá te entendamos. Además, no dices cuál es el problema que tiene el código actual ¿? ¿Qué debería hacer que no hace?

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta: Me refiero a seleccionar los value de los inputs creados y guardarlso en una variable, para poder utilizarlos luego, por ejemplo usarlos en calculos o imprimirlos en pantalla.